# Why does gzip compression not work for files processed by PHP?

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, compression, gzip

I have two files named `test.html` and `test.php` on my server, having the same content:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <title>TEMPLATE</title>
</head>
<body>

  TEXT

</body>
</html>
```

Besides that I have a `.htaccess`-files with the following content:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.(php3|php4|php5|php6|html|htm) $1\.php

AddType x-mapp-php5.5 .php
AddHandler x-mapp-php5.5 .php

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
</Ifmodule>
```

Requesting `test.html` returns the following headers:

```
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Fri, 01 Jul 2016 08:32:04 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=2, max=200
Server: Apache
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
x-powered-by: PHP/5.5.36
```

After uncommenting the rewrite part (thus using HTML without beeing processed by PHP), the response headers are:

```
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 186
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Fri, 01 Jul 2016 08:42:22 GMT
Etag: "xxxxxxxx-xx-xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
Keep-Alive: timeout=2, max=200
Last-Modified: Fri, 01 Jul 2016 08:42:03 GMT
Server: Apache
Vary: Accept-Encoding
```

It's exactly the same content and exactly the same header, but why is the content not compressed, when it is returned by PHP?

Comment: Apache will not handle PHP output compression because that's in the responsibility of PHP. Is php output compression enabled? (http://php.net/manual/en/zlib.configuration.php#ini.zlib.output-compression)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following line in your **.htaccess**

```
php_value zlib.output_compression 1
```

to enable PHP output compression.

More information at http://php.net/manual/en/zlib.configuration.php#ini.zlib.output-compression